# About the continuous function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, limits

Can the following function can be extended to continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$,

$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(2xy)}{x^2+y^2}$

if yes how one can show that?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be continuous?

Comment: what I know about when a function is continuous is something when $Lim_{a,b}$$f(x,y)=f(a,b)$. But regarding this question I do not understand what it mean to show that can we extend this to a continuous function or not.

Comment: You should check if the limit of $f$ exists if $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. If limit exists then define it $f(0,0)$, if doesn't then you can't extend.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=0, y=\frac{1}{n}$, then
$$f(x,y)=f\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)=0\to 0.$$
Take $x=y=\frac{1}{n}$, then
$$f(x,y)=f\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{\sin \frac{2}{n^2}}{\frac{2}{n^2}}\to1.$$

Hence the function $f$ is discontinious at $(0,0)$, independently of the value $f(0,0).$

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can.

Consider the limit of the function for $(x, y)$ approaching the origin in some direction $(x, mx)$: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(2mx^2)}{(x^2 + m^2 x^2)}$. This tends to $\frac {2m}{1+m^2}$, taking any value in range $[-1..1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof that the limit in $(0,0)$ doesn't exists.

You can write:

$$\frac{\sin(2xy)}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\sin(2xy)}{2xy} \cdot \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}.$$
The first member always goes to $1$, while the second causes some troubles. In fact if you use polar coordinates $(x,y) = (\rho \cos \vartheta, \rho \sin \vartheta)$, you get
$$\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{2 \rho^2 \cos\vartheta \sin\vartheta}{\rho^2} = \sin 2\vartheta.$$
Thus the limit in $(0,0)$ depends on "the angle with which you go to zero".